# I'm writing a c code on strings array. I would like to check the user input on the go to see if the user already input the same word before

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

This is a part of my code. I would like for screenWord function to receive the whole array (user-input values), and the current input word. It is supposed to check if the current word was already in the array. If it was entered then the function should print out "This word already exists".

```
int screenWord (char (*arrOfWords)[20],char* word,int count)
{
    //this will break out of the loop calling the function
    if (strcmp(word,"end")==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    //the part i use to check
    for (int i=0;i<count+1;i++)
    {

        /*i print out to see what value is currently there
        printf("%s %s\n",arrOfWords[i], word);*/

         // i want it to continue checking the whole array if the current word is not equal to the ith word, but it does not work.
        if (!(strcmp(arrOfWords[i],word)))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
          printf("This word already exists. Please enter another word");
        }      
    }
}
```

I am supposed to make the code look  like this.

Enter a word(Enter 'end'to quit):tiger

Enter a word(Enter 'end'to quit):cat

Enter a word(Enter 'end'to quit):cat

This word already exists. Please enter another word.

Enter a word(Enter 'end'to quit):eagle

Enter a word(Enter 'end'to quit):end

5 words in the list : tiger dog cat eagle mouse

Enter a word to search (Enter 'end'to quit):tiger

This word is in the list.

Enter a word to search (Enter 'end'to quit):bird

This word is NOT in the list.

Enter a word to search (Enter 'end'to quit):end

```
/*this is my full code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* askWord (char *str);
void printArray (char (*arrOfWords)[20],int count);
void searchWord (char (*arrOfWords)[20],int count);
int main() {
    
    char arrOfWords [10][20];
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        char* checkWord= askWord(arrOfWords[i]);
        count++;
        int result= screenWord (arrOfWords, checkWord,count);
        
        if (result==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (result==1)
        {
            printf("This word already exists. Please enter another word.\n");
        }
        
    }
    
    printArray(arrOfWords,count);

    searchWord(arrOfWords,count);
    
    return 0;
    
}
char* askWord (char *str)
{
    printf("\nEnter a word (Enter 'end' to quit): ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    return str;
}

int screenWord (char (*arrOfWords)[20],char* word,int count)
{
    if (strcmp(word,"end")==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n",arrOfWords[i], word);
        if (arrOfWords[i+1] && strcmp(word, arrOfWords[i+1])==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        continue;
    }
}

void printArray (char (*arrOfWords)[20],int count)
{
    printf("%d words is in the list\n",count-1);
    for (int i=0;i<count-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",arrOfWords[i]);
    }
}

void searchWord (char (*arrOfWords)[20],int count)
{   
    char searchWord[20];
    int i=0;
    printf("\nEnter a word to search (Enter 'end' to quit):");
    scanf("%s",searchWord);
    while(strcmp(searchWord,"end")!=0)
    {
             if (strcmp(searchWord,arrOfWords[i])==0)
            {

                printf("This word is in the list.\n");
                //continue;
            }
        else
            {
                printf("This word is NOT in the list.\n");
                //continue;
            }
        i++;
       
        printf("\nEnter a word to search (Enter 'end' to quit):");
        scanf("%s",searchWord);
        i=0;
        
    }
}*/
```

Comment: And what is your question or problem? For starters, do read the [strcmp manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) and note what it returns - 0 for match. `if (!(strcmp(arrOfWords[i],word)))` seems to be the condition you think is checking for words that are not equal when in fact it should be the opposite condition.

Comment: strcmp returns 0 when it successfully finds a match and since the if statement is the last thing in the loop you don't need the continue so the if statement could just be `if (!strcmp(arrOfWords[i],word)) printf("This word already exists. Please enter another word");`

Comment: I bet you want `i<count` instead of `i<count+1`.